# how to read data from json parser

Tags: json

```
 protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json)
        {
        if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing())
        {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (json != null)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(Home.this, json.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login successfully !!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //startActivity(new Intent(Home.this, NewWelcome.class));

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong user and password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

I want to read data from "JSONObject json" like user name and store it into string variable please help me !!!

like this data on Json object

```
"{
    "0": 8,
    "S_No": 8,
    "1": "Sachin Palve",
    "User_name": "Sachin Palve",
    "2": "sachinpalve5@gmail.com",
    "Email_id": "sachinpalve5@gmail.com",
    "3": "12345",
    "Password": "12345",
    "4": "Pune",
    "Place": "Pune",
    "5": "9860629293",
    "Contact_no": "9860629293",
    "6": "yes",
    "TC_approve": "yes",
    "7": "SPU93008",
    "User_id": "SPU93008"
}"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are reading it from javascript something like this will get you access to fields 0, S_No

if json is the object data

$var1 = json.0 ;
$var2 = json.S_No;
etc...

Answer (score 0):

pay attention to the object in single quotes to double quotes not escape

```js
var jsonStringData = '{ "0": 8, "S_No": 8, "1": "Sachin Palve", "User_name": "Sachin Palve", "2": "sachinpalve5@gmail.com", "Email_id": "sachinpalve5@gmail.com", "3": "12345", "Password": "12345", "4": "Pune", "Place": "Pune", "5": "9860629293", "Contact_no": "9860629293", "6": "yes", "TC_approve": "yes", "7": "SPU93008", "User_id": "SPU93008" }';

var dataobj = JSON.parse(jsonStringData);
console.log(dataobj);
```